# how to Resize Quick TIme Player to the size of an HTML/CSS DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, quicktime

I am using Quick time via javascript so that I can play video on my web browser. I want to resize the video so that it fits the size of the DIV. The problem is that when the player launches the video the size of the DIV remains the same but the player gets out of the DIV. I want the size of the DIV remain the same doesnt matter if the player can not be fully shown or resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you setting the size of the player? If you set the `<object>` `width` and `height` attributes to a certain number of pixels it should respect that. Whilst you can set `width: 100%;` with CSS, if that makes it resize with a liquid layout many plugins won't resize themselves after loading.

Unless you absolutely must play back old-school `.mov` files, I would strongly recommend avoiding the embedded video players today, and especially QuickTime which many Windows users will not have. Video on the web today is primarily done with Flash players. HTML5 `<video>` with fallback to Flash is nice to have for the newer browsers.